# Variable gets changed after executing function in Jupyter Notebook Python 3.7.1

Tags: python, function, local-variables

So I have a Python problem concerning variable scopes. I wrote a user-defined function to calculate moving average related numbers, but it overwrites the variable I pass into it.

The function takes in a pandas Data Array and an integer and calculates percentages based on moving averages. I load the variable myArray, which is a pandas array, then call the function and try to store the output in a new variable.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def calc_Util(columnRange,periods):

    columnRange2 = pd.DataFrame(columnRange)
    numRows = columnRange2.shape[0]
    numCols  = columnRange2.shape[1]
    outputRange = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(shape=(columnRange2.shape)),columns=columnRange2.columns)

    for c in range(numCols):
        maxColumn = columnRange2.iloc[:,c].rolling(window=periods).max().fillna(method='bfill')
        for r in range(numRows):

            outputRange.iloc[r,c] = columnRange2.iloc[r,c]/maxColumn[r]

    return outputRange


myArray = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(8000,6)*10)
myArray2 = myArray
myArray2.iloc[:,range(4,5)] = calc_Util(myArray.iloc[:,range(4,5)],180*24)
```

I would expect myArray2 to be a copy of myArray, but with an updated fifth column. However, after running this code, the Jupyter Notebook console shows me that also myArray's fifth column has been changed to the calculation values.

Comment: `myArray2 = myArray` does NOT make a separate copy of `myArray`.  It makes another _name_ that refers to the _same value_.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by John Gordon, the error was created by the missunderstanding of `myArray2 = myArray`, which creates a new name for the same array, but not a new array object itself. Hence working with `myArray2 = myArray.copy()` solves the problem.